# A tool or extension to do "fullscreen" like tiling

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell-extension, fullscreen, tiling

I would like to tile two windows side by side, such that both windows appear as if they are "fullscreen" i.e. no window borders, gnome top bar etc.

In other words, I want windows to be like "fullscreen" but withing their allocated area only, (i.e. half of the screen)

I have tried many extensions and combinations there of but could not achieve the desired result.

Please let me know if you know a way to achieve this. I am ok with command line based solutions but quick hotkey based solutions will be preferred.
Please refer to the screenshot below.
Thanks.
[image: Screenshot]

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this effect by

- Installing an extension that hides the top panel (search "hide panel"). You will probably will prefer [Hide Top Bar](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/545/hide-top-bar/) by tuxor1337, because that extension features an option to only hide the top panel when a window takes the space (intellihide).
- Installing an extension like "[Pixel Saver](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/723/pixel-saver/)" (also in the Ubuntu software center, `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-pixelsaver`) that merges title bar with the (now hidden) top bar.

You continue tiling in the usual way, i.e. using the default keybindings, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Left/Right</kbd>, or dragging the windows to the left or right side of the screen (provided "Edge Tiling" is enabled in "Tweaks", which is so by default).

Comment: Thanks. It works well with applications that do not have title bar integrated with the applications menu (for example terminal, gimp etc). But for applications which have applications menu integrated with titlebar, (for example evince, firefox) the titlebar stills shows up.

Comment: This is not a titlebar. These are Client Side decorations, controlled by the application itself, and not by the window manager. You cannot remove these. Firefox though can be configured to have a traditional title bar.

Comment: thanks for the help, I ended up splitting my screen into two virtual monitors using fakeXrandr. It worked like a charm.

Comment: And how does that solve the issue with the applications menu integrated with the titlebar? Also, if you are fine with your own solution, please write it out here as an answer (with sufficient detail so users can reproduce) and accept it. That is perfectly fine here, and is then useful for other users.

Comment: You can just full-screen the application using F11 or other such shortcut. It hides the application menu and the title-bar. And the application becomes "full-screen" in one half of the screen. It is exactly what I wanted and asked in the original question.

Comment: Again, then please post this solution as an answer, so that other users looking for this can also try this out. Also feel free to accept the answer yourself. Currently, you question remains without the answer you expected (and found yourself).